# VS2012 copies .xml and .pdf to Release from NuGet

Tags: build, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I've just started working with Visual Studio 2012 and NuGet and I really like it. A couple of the packages I'm using - AutoFac and CommonServiceLocator, for example - have .xml and maybe .pdb files in adidtion to the .dll. When I build, VS2012 copies these files to bin/release on a RELEASE build - I get .dll, .xml, and .pdb. That's great for debug, but I'd prefer it didn't happen in release.

I confirmed my Build settings for the projects that they are not generating debug symbols. It seems to be related to packages I got from NuGet.

How do I control that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the package owners included these files in their package definitions as library files.  NuGet freely lets folks do this, and most of the other behavior you're seeing is default behavior for Visual Studio when .xml and .pdb files are the same directory as a referenced assembly.

You can contact the package owners about your concerns, but as you've surmised it's safe to remove them from a site prior to publishing.

Comment: **No, Thank You!!** Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).